# jQuery not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

This is the site: www.alweso.2ap.pl

I can't make it work on mobile phones (resizing the browser works fine).

I finally figured out that a big part of the problem is the fact that jQuery on this website doesn't seem to work on mobile phones. What should I do about it?

I know there's something like jQuery mobile, but is it a must to install it? The typical jQuery library shouldn't be enough?

Comment: jQuery should work fine on mobile devices. jQuery mobile is something else entirely, you don't need it. Perhaps the code is breaking when viewed on a mobile device? Have you tried looking at your javascript errors? That often requires remote debugging.

Comment: Thnx for fast answer! How can I check for JavaScript errors? I know how to validate html and css, but about javascript - no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery works on phones.  jQuery mobile is just for more mobile-centric functionality.

I noticed you have a bunch of errors on your website in the developer console.  I'd fix those first:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.alweso.2ap.pl/js/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.alweso.2ap.pl/nivo-slider.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.alweso.2ap.pl/lib/jquery.bxslider.css
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier arrow-bounce.js:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input onemore.js:12
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.alweso.2ap.pl/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome-4.0.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3
```

It's possible the mobile browser might not be able to recover from these errors, but a desktop one can.

You can find these errors in the JavaScript Console.  For Chrome you can open it in a couple ways:

- Use the keyboard shortcut Command - Option - J (Mac) or Control -Shift -J (Windows/Linux).
- Select View > Developer > JavaScript Console.

Comment: Big thnx! I'm taking a look at it now, hopefully it will work.

Comment: I managed to get rid of almost all the errors you've mentioned, plus I deleted some code that I wasn't using anymore and the javascript seems to be working!

Big thnx again, there's still a lot of problems on mobile devices, but at least one less thnx to your help :)

Comment: Glad to hear, best of luck!